# Adding cv-qualifers to a typedef-ed function type

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

In the following code, the last two `static_assert`s fail.
But why? Where should I put the `const` to make the assertations pass?

```
#include <type_traits>

// these are ok
static_assert(!std::is_same_v<void(), const void()>);
static_assert(!std::is_same_v<void(), void() const>);
static_assert(!std::is_same_v<const void(), void() const>);
// so 'void()', 'const void()', 'void() const' are all distinct types

using F = void(); // or 'typedef void F()'; 

static_assert(std::is_same_v<const F, const void()>); // error!
static_assert(std::is_same_v<const F, void() const>); // error!
```

The above code may seem too abstract and like a pure *language-lawyer* code, so I'll explain in detail what led me to the question.

#### Real-life example

I had the following code:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <class>
struct X;

template <class T, class U>
struct X<T U::*> {
    using t = T;
};

struct A {
    void member() {}
};

static_assert(std::is_same_v<
    X<decltype(&A::member)::t, void()
>); // this is ok
```

My intention was that the `X<pointer-to-member-function>::t` would be the type of the *written-outside-the-class* version of the `member-function` (You probably know what I mean). And the code above runs fine, that is, the `static_assert` passes.

Next, I changed the definition of `A` to the following:

```
struct A {
    void const_member() const {}
};
```

and the `static_assert` to:

```
static_assert(std::is_same_v<
    X<decltype(&A::const_member)::t, void()
>);
```

Now the `static_assert` fails.
But then I noticed that if I changed the `void()` in the `static_assert` to `void() const` it compiles. So I changed the partial speciailization of X to the following (so that `X::t` would be `void()`)

```
template <class T, class U>
struct X<const T U::*> {
    using t = T;
};
```

but then, the compiler complains:

```
 error: incomplete type ‘X<void (A::*)() const>’ used in nested name specifier
   17 |             X<decltype(&A::const_member)>::t, void()
```

Apparently, the specialization is not selected.

Comment: `const void()` is "function whose return type is `const void`". `void() const` is "member function only callable on a `const` object" (`const` here essentially applies to the implicit `this` parameter); also known as an [abominable function type](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0172r0.html). `const F` is "`const` function type" (something that I don't believe is expressible without a typedef, and in any case `const` is ignored here since functions are not objects and can't be mutated anyway). It's roughly the same difference as `const int*` vs `int* const`.

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik Ah, now I know what `const F` means. Then I guess producing the types `const void()` and `void() const` is not achievable by just adding `const` to `F`.

Comment: No, for the same reason that `const int*` is not achievable by adding `const` to `P` defined as `using P = int*` (in the unlikely case this is not obvious: `const P` would be "a const pointer to a non-const `int`", same as `int* const`; whereas `const int*` is "a non-const pointer to a const `int`").